# Why html is so popular, is there any alternative?

Tags: html

I can not find alternative of mark up language.
Is there any alternative of HTML?
 Like every other language there are so much option to choose.

Comment: There are templating languages that are a bit nicer in terms of syntax such as Pug, Handlebars, Mustache, etc that compile *into HTML* but there is no actual alternative. The web uses HTTP; hyper-text transfer protocol, and HTML is *hyper-text* markup language.

Comment: there was a time when we thought it would all be XML + CSS, but that failed.  Getting multiple browsers to all understand one markup language more or less the same is hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

If by alternative you mean something that web browsers can understand, not really unless you count XHTML and SVG. But if you mean alternatives that you can use to mark things up, then yes, there are many:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_markup_languages
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_markup_language
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_document_markup_languages
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_syndication_markup_languages

You get the idea…